# How can you pretty print all javascript files automatically in Google Chrome?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

In the sources tab in google chrome dev tools, you can pretty print minified javascript code to make it more readable by clicking the curly braces at the bottom. However, I have to manually do this every single time I open a minified javascript file. Does google chrome have a way to automatically pretty print every file I open? If chrome can not do this, is there a chrome extension for this?